# How do I set Gnome's default open behavior for file types?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, mime-type

I'd like to set 10.10 to open MP3 files in Muinshee when I open them from a file manager. I don't really like Totem very much, and opening all of Banshee is a little bit too heavy for just playing a one-off audio file I grabbed from the web, or a song that one of my friends recorded and then sent to me over Empathy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click over a file, properties, there is an "Open With" tab, set the default application there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to System > Preferences > Preferred Applications and do it from there.