# I have installed Visual studio code, ran the "Code" exe, but how do I add it as default IDE?

Tags: executable, ide

I have installed Visual studio code and am able to run the "Code" application.

How do I add it as default IDE or at least as an option in the "Related applications" menu?

Please see the images:

## Image 1:

[image]

---

## Image 2 - The editor won't be found in the list at all till it's end:

[image]

---

## Image 3 - That's the directory in which I manually activate the VSC program:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set Gnome's default open behavior for file types?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11387/how-do-i-set-gnomes-default-open-behavior-for-file-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make a .desktop file.  Edit a file in `/usr/share/applications` named `code.desktop`:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
```

Then type in the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Visual Studio Code
Comment=Visual Studio Code is a source code editor developed by Microsoft for Windows, Linux and OS X.
Exec=/home/user/Desktop/VSCode-linux-x64/code
Path=/home/user/Desktop/VSCode-linux-x64/
Icon=/usr/share/icons/path/to/your/icon.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;Development;
```

... replacing `user` with your username and `path/to/your/icon.svg` with the name of whatever icon you want to use.

Now make sure the permissions are correct:

```
sudo chmod 644 code.desktop
```

Now right click your code file (colors.css).  Select `Properties`.  Then select the `Open with` tab, and search for the application you want it to open with by default.  Click on that application and select the `Set as default` button at the bottom right.

Comment: You mean to make a symbolic link in the desktop and move it to the /usr/share/applications?

Comment: Not quite, but close.  You're creating a .desktop file (application reference file) in the default application reference folder, such that it should be detected automatically.  The .desktop file in turn references your program.